# swift2 print doesnn't work in NSView subclass

Tags: nsview, swift2

Since println() changed to print() in Swift2, I can no longer debug using print statements inside NSViews, as print method simply causes the print dialog box to show...

What am I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Swift's print is being 'hidden' by NSView's print, you can just specify:

```
Swift.print("Hello")
```